# GMB mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1 not returning all locations

Tags: google-api, google-playground

GMB API v1 does not return all locations.

On Google developer playground if I run something like `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/my_account_number/locations?`

it would return all my locations where I'm a owner

If I use the new API and run `https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/my_account_number/locations?read_mask=title` it would not return all locations.

I verified if anything is different on the location, but could not find anything.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I have less than 100 locations. I also asked in the google support and the answer was:
There was likely an error with the pageSize, we're still trying to troubleshoot the problem you reported and will follow up soon with a response if we are able to replicate your issue. In the meantime you will likely need to establish the pageSize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add &pageSize=100

https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/my_account_number/locations?read_mask=title&pageSize=100

pageToken maybe required if your total locations is more than 100.